# Overriding UserControl Properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm brand new to **WPF**, so I'm a bit at a loss for how to do this. I created a very simple visual `UserControl` today that consists of a grid, displaying a circle with two dotted lines crossing through it. The intent is to display a circle of a given radius size. I'd *like* to be able to hide Height and Width, and use a custom property called `RadiusSize` to set the size of the control.

The Code Behind defines the `RadiusSize` dependency property, as such:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusSizeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RadiusSize", typeof(double), typeof(Radius));

public double RadiusSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusSizeProperty); }
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(RadiusSizeProperty, value);
        Height = value * 2;
        Width = value * 2;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RadiusSize");
    }
}
```

There's no visible change to the Height or Width property when setting up the XAML for a given `Radius` control and passing it a `RadiusSize` unfortunately. If removed, they just default to `Auto`. Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  No, you are not doing it right.

Its a bit hard to tell how you're setting width/height on the circle, but the obvious newbie error you have in your code is that you're doing stuff within the setter of a DependencyProperty.

DP `Binding`s are *not accessed through the getters/setters of your property.*  The binding system works behind the scenes, so if you bind to a DP on your class the getters/setters won't be called when the bindings are updated.

So, what are the alternatives?  Many.  You can add a [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.aspx) instance to the property declaration that specifies a callback, and in that callback update other properties... or you can avoid it altogether.  I'd go with the second.

If I were going to create a UserControl with an ellipse and some other drawings in it, I'd just slap the visuals in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) and have it automatically stretch to the size of the UserControl, and forget the whole radius thing.

*But* if you're still interested in the radius, you could use an IValueConverter to do the work.

```
public class RadiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, /*snip*/)
    {
        // check null, type, and double.NaN here
        return (double)value * 2;
    }
    /* snip, on the round trip same as before but / 2 */
}
```

Then, define a `Radius` property in your UserControl as you have, and

```
<UserControl x:Class="Derp"
    Width="{Binding Radius, Converter={StaticResource RadiusConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} />
<!-- snip -->
```

Comment: +1 for the thorough rundown. I'd give you another +1 for the *derp*, but alas, I cannot. I'll look into the `ViewBox` to start. I wasn't quite sure what that did... (I wasn't kidding when I said I was new to this. This is the first time I've touched WPF in any real capacity)

Comment: @KChaloux: Once you're over that learning curve, you're in for an awesome ride.

Comment: It's already pretty neat... Simple visual niceties like slight gradient backgrounds and drawing geometry was the biggest pain in the world when working with Winforms.

Comment: Actually, could I get some clarification on the converter? I looked into that method, but ran into an issue where my RadiusConverter couldn't be invoked within the <UserControl> definition because it couldn't be resolved. Is there a declaration I should be including, or something?

Comment: @kchaloux you have to add a resource in xaml with that key name.  Search for static resources on MSDN (sorry, on phone).

Answer (score 2):

the problem is you have placed your logic into the setter of the 'clr wrapper property' around the DependencyProperty. This does not work in WPF. You should put your code into a DependencyPropertyChangedCallback in the declaration of your DependencyProperty. Take a look at [This tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html)

Aside from that, you can use an Ellipse to draw a circle on screen, instead of having to implement your own.

What does your RaisePropertyChanged method do? You should not implement INotifyPropertyChanged in DependencyObject based classes.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial. I'll look into that. As for using ellipse, that's exactly what I'm already doing. But the control also includes lines intersecting the center to mark the radius, and I'd rather bundle them together in a control that handles all that, rather than duplicating my lines and ellipses over and over again. While I'm at it, I'm trying to limit input to ensure that the width and height are equal.

Comment: If you want to force Width equal Height or Height equal Width (Always), you will have to override metadata for one of them and register a dependencypropertychangedcallback to set the other. I think that would be wrong anyways, you should not force size properties in WPF controls. Just place the whole thing inside a ViewBox and set its stretch property to Uniform

Comment: What if I don't want the internal items to scale in all aspects? For example, when placed inside a ViewBox, the thickness of the lines scales up as well.

Comment: @KChaloux: For a line, you have to set its start and end points where you want them, if you don't want the visual to scale in all aspects.  You can override [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) to set your line points at the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine, just, when you set the height of your control you are probably not modifying the height of the circle inside, try set height of circle  and grid that you contain also.

Answer (score 0):

As another poster pointed out, you won't be able to set Height and Width using the property system. Instead, if what you want is to automatically set the Height and Width of the control, you will want to define a callback for your `RadiusSizeProperty` DependencyProperty.

Something like this will set Height and Width for you when you set RadiusSize:

```
    Public Shared RadiusSizeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RadiusSize",
                                                             GetType(Double),
                                                             GetType(Radius),
                                                             New PropertyMetadata(0.5, Sub(s, e)

                                                                                           Dim p As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs = e
                                                                                           Dim o As DependencyObject = s
                                                                                           o.SetValue(HeightProperty, p.NewValue)
                                                                                           o.SetValue(WidthProperty, p.NewValue)
                                                                                       End Sub))
```